# Proof that $\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}2^{i}=3^{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

The following sum came up in a combinatorial argument. I know what it equals thanks to Wolfram Alpha, but I'm not sure how to show it

$$\sum_{i=0}^n {n\choose i}2^{i}=3^{n}$$

Comment: This question is extremely unclear IMO. What is the $\sum$'s subscript? How could $0^n$ multiplied by anything be equal to anything other than $0$???

Comment: @barakmanos it should be clear now?

Comment: Yes, much better now. I'd use induction BTW...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525266/prove-sum-binom-nk-2k-3n-using-the-binomial-theorem or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258009/how-to-prove-that-sum-r-0n-binomnr2r-3n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint**:$ $ $ $ $ $

$$3^n = (2+1)^n$$

Comment: Oh wow, this is why you don't do math at 5 am

Comment: @StellaBiderman No matter the experience level, time of day and  age, things like this will happen all the time. I promise :P

Answer (score 4):

For the record, the proof 5xum alludes to goes as follows:

The Binomial Theorem states that $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{I=0}^n{n \choose i} a^ib^{n-i}$$ For $a=2,b=1$, we notice that our sum is of the above form.

Answer (score 4):

As a combinatorial proof, both sides of the equality count the number of partitions of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into three ordered parts $(A,B,C)$.

- Method 1: For each element, we add it to $A$, $B$, or $C$, giving $3^n$ possibilities.
- Method 2: We choose $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ elements to be added to $B \cup C$, and the rest go into $A$.  Of those $i$ elements, we add them to $B$ or $C$ one by one, giving $2^i$ possibilities.  This totals $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} 2^i$.

Comment: (Note too that this instantly generalizes to the full binomial theorem, using $m+n$ ordered parts rather than just $1+2$)